# Computation question regarding a power series solution to differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

[image]

Above is the question, Below is how I chose to attack it.
[image]

My approach is to compute the derivative and second derivatives of J2, and then substitute them into the given differential equation to prove that J2 is indeed a power series solution. However, during computation, I found that J2 is not a power series solution. Have I done something wrong in my computation, especially when I shifted index, or was the question incorrect?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, but I meant the two summations themselves are different even without the negative sign taken into consideration.

Comment: You could do a sanity check by typing the first few terms of the power series into Maple/Mathematica and checking if the lowest coefficients of $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-4)y$ vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the Bessel Function of the first kind you are given is simply wrong:
$$J_2(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^k}{k!(\color {red}{k+2})!2^{2k+2}}x^{2k+2}$$

Where you have a factorial of $k+3$ at the denominator. The correct general formula is:
$$J_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^k}{k!({k+n})!2^{2k+n}}x^{2k+n}$$